If $\Gamma$ is consistent, then $\rho(\Gamma)$ ($\Gamma$ with only even constants) is consistent.
Let $L$ be a formal language. Let $\Gamma$ be a set of formulas of $L$. Let also $\rho: \{c_i\} \to \{c_i\}$ be a function defined by $\rho(c_i) = c_{2i}$. That is, a function which takes each constant to an even constant. Extend the definition of $\rho$ to terms and formulas in the most obvious manner so that if $\tau$ is a term, $\rho(\tau)$ is the same term with all constants changed to even ones. Similarly for $\rho(\phi)$ when $\phi$ is a formula and let $\rho(\Gamma) = \{\rho(\phi) \mid \phi \in \Gamma\}$.
Question: Show that if $\Gamma$ is consistent, then $\rho(\Gamma)$ is consistent.
My (partial) Proof: Suppose towards contradiction that $\Gamma$ is consistent but $\rho(\Gamma)$ is inconsistent. Then $\rho(\Gamma) \vdash (\phi \wedge \neg\phi)$ for some $\phi$. This means there is a sequence $\langle \sigma_1,...,\sigma_n \rangle$ such that $\sigma_n \equiv (\phi \wedge \neg\phi)$. I would like to claim that something like $\langle e(\sigma_1),...,e(\sigma_n) \rangle $ is a proof of $e(\phi \wedge \neg\phi)$ from $\Gamma$ and thus a contradiction. The question is which function $e$ to use.
The most obvious candidate is $\rho^{-1}$. However, this can only be defined for even constants but $\sigma_i$ could be an instance of an axiom or MP and thus contain odd constants as well. If I define a new function $e$ which behaves as $\rho^{-1}$ only for even constants, I am still going to have some problem in telling it how to behave on odd ones. In particular, it will most likely override constants already used. How could I go around this problem?

Since $\rho(\Gamma)$ does not mention odd constants at all, you can show (if you want to be formal, induct on the length of proof) that any proof from $\rho(\Gamma)$ is still valid if you just replace all odd constants with basically anything else - even constants or variables, say. So after that you get a proof of a contradiction from $\rho(\Gamma)$ which never mentions any odd constant. Now just apply $\rho^{-1}$.

@DavidGao If I convert a proof of $\phi$ from $\rho(\Gamma)$, that is $\langle \sigma_1,...,\sigma_n \rangle$ to a proof involving only even constants, I will have to apply some function to the $\sigma_i$. Presumably $\rho$. However, if $\sigma_i$ was originally in $\Gamma$, then $\rho(\sigma_i)$ will no longer be in $\rho(\Gamma)$, but $\rho(\rho(\Gamma))$ which is not the same.

I’m not sure I understand what you meant. What I said is the following: if a set of formula $\Omega$ does not mention a constant $c$, then a proof $\langle \sigma_1, \cdots, \sigma_n \rangle$ from $\Omega$ is still valid if you replace all instances of $c$ in $\sigma_i$ to some other constant $d$, or some variable $x$ (that does not already occur boundedly in any $\sigma_i$).

Ah, I suppose I see what you meant. No, you’re not supposed to apply $\rho$. Instead, apply a function that sends even constants to themselves and odd constants to some even constants (for concreteness, say $c_0$).

Yes I think I understand. What I said was that if I replace all odd constants appearing in $\langle \sigma_1,...,\sigma_n\rangle$ with some even ones, I am worried I might be using again some of the constants already been used and thus disrupt the proof. Whereas you are saying this is not an issue. If I use some function $e$ which changes only odd constants to even ones, and leaves even ones unchanged, then it should work right?

Yes, it will work insofar as your set of formulae at the start do not mention odd constants, which is the case for $\rho(\Gamma)$.
